# Magento 2: The way to set custom DB for the ProductCollection in custom module

Tags: magento2

Is there any way to set custom DB for \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
only for 1 custom module that is using this collection?

I need to use another DB when iterating through productCollection in the custom module.

Answer (score 0):

I just made some code review. And there is no way to do it in the current version of Magento 2.

There is a way to do it only for your Resource collection as described in this article. 
maxpronko.com/blog/new-database-connection-in-magento-2

But you can't do it for the Product collection like it was in Magento 1.